# Generating relationships with chance percentage in Neo4j

Tags: python, database, csv, neo4j, probability

Consider a CSV file with over 1.300.000 rows that contain information about articles from arXiv. The structure of that file looks like this:

```
id,title,url,abstract,date,categories,authors
0,"Title1",http://arxiv.org/abs/0704.0001,"Blabla",2007-04-02,Phenomenology,"Balázs, C.;Berger, E. L.;Nadolsky, P. M."
```

I am importing it to Neo4j database. This is not an issue. However, I would like to create some pseudo random (maybe based on some made up probability model) relationships between the articles - citing.

I would like to generate (article1)-[:CITES]->(article2) relationships. But I want them not to be full random ones. I want to take in account that article can cite only older articles than itself and if articles are in the same category the chance that one cites another is much higher, also the same authors are boosting the chance of citing. Just trying to somewhat simulate the real world.

My question is - how would one approach that? Can it be done using Cypher? Or should I create (i.e. python) application, and how should I build it? Or maybe I should create them in the CSV as a column and then import it to Neo4j like so:

```
id,title,url,abstract,date,categories,authors,cites
100,"Test",http://test.test,"Desc",2018-03-25,Phenomenology,"XYZ, John","0;4;15;25;60;69;89"
```

Or maybe there is a tool that could help me? Or am I missing something? What is the best way (and maybe the easiest one) to create those relationships?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a cypher script to do it. 
For each article you have to create a random scoring function to find the best other cities.

And the result should be something like that :

```
MATCH (a:Article) WHERE size((a)-[:CITES]->(:Article)) = 0
WITH a LIMIT 100
  MATCH (b:Article) WHERE b.date < a.date 
 WITH 
  a, 
  b,
  CASE 
    WHEN a.categories = b.categories THEN rand()
    ELSE 0
  END AS catScore,
  CASE 
    WHEN a.authors = b.authors THEN rand()
    ELSE 0
  END AS catAuthor
  WITH a, b, catScore + 2* catAuthor AS score ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 1
    CREATE (a)-[:CITES]->(b)
    RETURN count(*)
```

You should execute this query many times, till its result is equal to **0**. (There is procedure fot that in **APOC** if you want).

This query will not work on your datamodel because the date is a string. I recommend you to store the *timestamp*, not the string date (there is also an **APOC** function to parse date), and to create an index on it.

Moreover, I think you have `Author` and `Category` nodes in your datamodel, no ? So you should adapt the query.

Comment: I installed APOC like you recommended. As I understand this timestamp  parsing function is called apoc.date.parse? I will check that out. Could you tell my what APOC procedure can query this till result is equal 0? 

Yes - Author and Category are nodes. I will try to adapt your code for this situation, thank you very much for this.